# The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, date, view

I have written a view in which date from table which is converted as

```
convert(varchar, date, 103)
```

and taken alias as DATE1 and then I have written query as follows :

```
select DATE1  
from date_demo
WHERE  MONTH(DATE1) = '12'
```

I want to retrieve only specific records with the month = 'december' that is 12

I got an error:

> The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.

This is in SQL Server 2005 pls help me

Comment: why would you not use the underlying date column in the where clause instead of explicitly converting to string then implicitly back to datetime?  Are you trying to make your server cry?

Answer (score 2):

As david suggested ,you should be using the date column instead of converting to string then back to datetime column.

However when you convert it back to datetime ,you need to specify the [Date Time Style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187928.aspx)

```
select DATE1  from date_demo
WHERE  MONTH(convert(datetime,DATE1,103))= '12'
```

Moreover you need to specify the length of varchar data type Read this artcile [bad habits to kick declaring varchar without length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Comment: That is not what the error is pointing to, and SQL can do the conversion from string to int just fine